# How to interpret the evidence ratio using BRMS in R?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, brms

I am running a frequentist multi-level meta-analysis. However a reviewer has requested a bayesian alternative, so I can provide Bayes Factors.

My summary of my code is as follows:

```
priors <- c(prior(normal(0, 1), class = Intercept),
        prior(cauchy(0, 0.5), class = sd))


m.brm <- brm(yi|se(se) ~ 1 + (1|StudyN),
         data = CONS_MERGED,
         prior = priors,
         iter = 4000, 
         sample_prior = "yes")

hyp <- hypothesis(m.brm, "Intercept > 0")
print(hyp)
```

output for 'hyp':

```r
Hypothesis Tests for class b:
       Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1 (Intercept) > 0     0.29       0.1     0.12     0.46        199         1
```

Am I right in interpreting Evid.Ratio as BF10 for the hypothesis that the meta-analytic estimate > 0.

Comment: The name of the famous program is R not r! I have edited for now ...